# Can we simplify this matrix using Vandermonde?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, analytic-geometry, approximation, 3d

**The background** has a close practical reference to (computer aided) 3D visualization techniques. It is about "melting" spheres using so-called Blinn objects (shortly "Blobs"):

[image]

For this we need a Gaussian function $g(q)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{-|q-c|^2}{2\sigma^2}}$, $q,c\in\mathbb{R}^3,\sigma\in\mathbb{R}^+$. The Blobs are given by the set: $B_g=\{q\in\mathbb{R}^3|g_{\sigma,c}(q)=k\}$. The variable $c$ is the center of a Blob. Varying $\sigma$ adjusts the radius of a Blob. Composing these Blobs leads to a "Blobby Surface" in which the Blobs $B_i$ are melted together. For this we use the implicit functions $g_i$ and constants $k_i$:

$$
f(q)=-k+\sum_{i=1}^ng_i(q)~~\text{where}~~k=\sum_{i=1}^nk_i
$$

**The challenge** is to replace the Gaussian function by a polynom to make calculations more efficient. This can be done by approximating $g$ using a polynomial $p(x)=a_0+a_2x^2+a_4x^4+\ldots+a_{2n}x^{2n}$, where we set $p(0)=g(0)=a_0$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}p(x)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x)$ for $x_1=t,x_2=2t,\ldots,x_n=nt$, $t\in\mathbb{R}^+$.

**The question** is: Using Vandermonde (or some similar tricks), can we simplify the resulting matrix equation that solves the coefficients of our polynomial:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    a_2\\
    a_4\\
    \vdots\\
    a_{2n}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
    2\cdot(1t) & 4\cdot(1t)^3 & \cdots & 2n\cdot(1t)^{2n-1}\\
    2\cdot(2t) & 4\cdot(2t)^3 & \cdots & 2n\cdot(2t)^{2n-1}\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    2\cdot(nt) & 4\cdot(nt)^3 & \cdots & 2n\cdot(nt)^{2n-1}& 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    g'(1t)\\
    g'(2t)\\
    \vdots\\
    g'(nt)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

I see that the matrix structure looks a little bit like it would allow simplification using Vandermonde. Maybe there exist some tricks that enable us to benefit from Vandermonde.

**For those who are interested** in the approximation result (in 3D):
The original "Blobby Surface" is depicted on the left and the approximated surface on the right:

$\require{HTML}
\newcommand{\mypic}[4][]{
\style{
display: inline-block;
background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/#4) no-repeat center;
 #1
}{\phantom{\Rule{#2}{#3}{0px}}}}$

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\mypic{280px}{300px}{4lD4xm.png}&
\mypic{280px}{300px}{cmNLWm.png}
\end{array}$$

The approximation of the Gaussian curve (red) by the polynomial (blue) looks as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient matrix $M$ of entries
$$
M_{ij}=(2j)(it)^{2j-1},\qquad i,j=1,\dots,n,
$$
can be factorized as
$$
M=diag(2,4,\dots,2n)V(1,4,\dots,n^2)diag(2t,(2t)^3,\dots,t^{2n-1})
$$
where $V(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is the Vandermonde matrix, with entries $V(x_1,\dots,x_n)_{i,j} = x_i^{j-1}$.

Thus to invert $M$ it is enough to invert the particular Vandermonde matrix $V(1,4,\dots,n^2)$. There are general formulae for the inverse of $V(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, though I do not know if they give anything explicit in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for working out this. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment, but I lack the reputation to comment; intended to help find pertinent background information and understanding.

The generalization of Blinn objects are [metaballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaball), where the Gaussian function $g()$ is replaced by an arbitrary real function; most typically a function of the distance to the center of each metaball component.

The most generic form for a metaball is
$$\sum_k g(x, y, z, x_k, y_k, z_k, w_k) \le C \tag{1}\label{BtV1}$$
where $x_k, y_k, z_k$ is a vector referring to the center of metaball component $k$, $w_k$ is the weight factor of said component, and $C$ is the isosurface threshold.  ($\eqref{BtV1}$ is true for the volume within the metaball; for the isosurface, the sum equals $C$.)

Typical form used in computer graphics is
$$\begin{aligned} g(x, y, z, x_k, y_k, z_k, w_k) &= w_k f(r_k^2) \\
r_k^2 &= (x - x_k)^2 + (y - y_k)^2 + (z - z_k)^2 \\
\end{aligned}$$
with $f(r_k^2) = r_k^{-4}$ (i.e. $f(x) = 1/x^2$) being a common choice.

Sometimes different support functions $f$ are used, so that the metaball equation used is actually
$$\sum_k w_k f_k(r_k^2) \le C$$

The reason squared distance is used, is that the square root operation is computationally relatively expensive, and using integer powers of distance squared avoids that, yielding a computationally more efficient (faster) object evaluation.

Comment: First of all, welcome to the community! And thank you for your comment on generalizing Blobs using metaballs, which is very useful here.

Comment: @EldarSultanow: Thank you! One of the reasons different support functions $f_k()$ are used, is when the metaball components themselves are animated/modified: different widths of the support function curve changes the apparent behaviour (consider e.g. narrow/tight $f()$ for "eyes" the metaball can "produce" to its surface).  I also forgot that many programmers use them but call them "blobs", so if looking for tips on *implementing* them efficiently in computer code, "blob" is also a term to look for.